# hover not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

i have a little issue with firefox, hover is not working.

CSS:

```
#mega_main_menu.mmt_1_menu > .menu_holder > .menu_inner > ul > li:hover > a *{ color: #f8f8f8; }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="mega_main_menu" class="nav_menu mmt_1_menu icons-left first-lvl-align-left first-lvl-separator-smooth direction-horizontal responsive-enable mobile_minimized-enable dropdowns_animation-none version-1-0-5 include-logo include-search">

 <div class="menu_holder" data-sticky="1" data-stickyoffset="164">

<div class="menu_inner">

<ul id="mega_main_menu_ul" class="mega_main_menu_ul menu-ul">

                                        <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom  menu-item-11  submenu_default_width columns"
                                            style="float: right"><a title="Standard" href="Contact.aspx" class="item_link"
                                                tabindex="1"><span><span class="link_text">Contact Us</span></span></a>
                                        </li>
</ul>
</div></div></div>
```

Please help me as soon as possible, i dont know what i m missing.

Comment: Do you have an online reference?

Comment: no no, reference is offline

Comment: What do you mean hover is not working? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Does your question mean it works in other browsers?

Comment: whenever i hover on Contact.aspx link, its font color is changed into white color. Its working good on Chrome, but when i do the same in firefox, on hover, i am not getting font color as white

Comment: @Rob in chrome it's working, but not in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i just removed the `*` as it isn't required for what you're trying to do

```
#mega_main_menu.mmt_1_menu > .menu_holder > .menu_inner > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Comment: But it is absolutely fine on all of my browsers, works fine in jsFiddle. *WHAT* is not working exactly?

Comment: Yes i just saw, its working on jsfiddle.net/WE2jB ,, but don't know what issue is coming

Comment: Well tell us what is not working for you, you aren't explaining the issue at all. "It's not working" is not explaining the issue, we cannot fix what we don't know

Answer (score 1):

The last bit of the selector (`a *`) means that the style is applied to anything *inside* that particular `a` tag, not the `a` tag itself. Removing `*` should solve this problem:

```
#mega_main_menu.mmt_1_menu > .menu_holder > .menu_inner > ul > li:hover > a { color: #f8f8f8; }
```